# Is a plugin for QGIS3 with the user interface defined by code acceptable for the repository?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3, free-software

I am working on a QGis3x plugin, I have created a minimal Plugin, the user interface (dialog) I have defined by code. Without using Qt Designer.
If I would like to upload this plugin to the QGIS repository, **For free use of the public**, would it be acceptable?

If not, how can I implement QTranslator in this case?